# How to disable Back button when we move Login to Home page in Ionic apps

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hi i am new for Ionic apps development and in every app after login we will go to Dashboard screen there we are not show back button and we are just killing the app if user press on back button,How can we do this in Ionic apps can some one help me please

### Login :

```
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  logToHomePage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }
}
```

### HomePage:-

```
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  // make UsersPage the root (or first) page
  rootPage: any = DashboardTabsPage;
  pages: Array<{ title: string, icon: string, component: any, openTab? : any }>;

  constructor() {
    // set our app's pages
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'DashBoard',icon: 'home', component: DashboardTabsPage},
      { title: 'List', icon: 'home',component: ListsTabsPage },
      { title: 'NoTabs', icon: 'home',component: NoTabsPage },
    ];
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component,{ openTab: page.openTab });
  }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296999/ionic-2-disabling-back-button-for-a-specific-view - there is quite a lot of answers for this question

Comment: @Adrian Sawicki using that code we can just hide Back button and in android devices having back buttons and in my case i want to kill app when we Home page

Comment: sorry it's a bit hard to read at the moment. So you want to kill the app when user press back button when he is on Home page or you want to kill app when user press back button and he get into home page?

Comment: Want to kill the app when user press back button when he is on Home page

Comment: In all apps same flow is running right once User logged In then enter to home page then when he press back button app need to close

Comment: edit your question so there won't be misunderstanding and add your home component html template - so we can see all needed code.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `hideBackButton` to your html to hide back button.

Example:

```
<ion-navbar hideBackButton>
```

You can use any button to close the app.
in yout html:

```
<button (click)="exitApp()">Close<button> //or you can just name it whatever you want or just put some icon
```

in your .ts:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public plt: Platform) {}

exitApp(){
   this.plt.exitApp();
}
```

Comment: i am not asking only hide the back button,After logged in we come to Home page there when we tap back button app must be close

Comment: in real time apps seems to be like this

Comment: This is only working for navigationbar back button not for device back button

Comment: Ahsant good idea thannk you is there any solution in ionic 4 to avoid logged in users to enter into login page and avoid logout users to back to app pages after logout

Answer (score 0):

you can override the back button with the registerBackButtonAction method of the Platform Ionic Api.

[https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonActionç](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction%C3%A7)

For example, in the constructor of your .ts File:

```
 constructor(public platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

        platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {


                    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: 'App termination',
                        message: 'Do you want to close the app?',
                        buttons: [{
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            role: 'cancel',
                            handler: () => {
                                console.log('Application exit prevented!');
                            }
                        },{
                            text: 'Close App',
                            handler: () => {
                                this.platform.exitApp(); // Close this application
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                    alert.present();
                }
            }
        });
```