# go back button sidemenu

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I added a SIDEMENU in my project as second page, and the first page is a screen only one image with a button for the second. But when I click the button, instead of showing the sidemenu button in the upper left corner, it is showing only the "back" arrow, but if I put my SIDEMENU page as the rootpage, it works perfectly. I just want to go to the second page and my sidemenu appear perfect and not like the "back" button. Please, if anyone understands me, help me: D

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title> Vida carioca </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

[it's this wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvszj.png)

[as i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK4yC.png)

Comment: It's difficult to help you when you don't include any of the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot, but i already edited

Comment: Have you tried `<ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">....</ion-navbar>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 - Disabling back button for a specific view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296999/ionic-2-disabling-back-button-for-a-specific-view)